# How to join a table from a string of comma delimited string of IDs?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of values like:

```
id | genre
-------------
1  | Puzzle
2  | RPG
3  | Action
4  | Fighter
5  | Adventure
```

And in another table, I have a string of comma delimited Ids that match the above table, like:

```
'1, 3, 5'
```

And I want my query to return this field as:

```
'Puzzle, Action, Adventure'
```

Also, maybe is there a smarter way to approach this problem than storing this string of ids?

Comment: You only want to use a query, or is ok to work in another language?

Comment: this is what 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: Your “another table” is broken. Put each ID in a separate row, then you can join them.

Comment: This is a good read, e4c5.. I don't see any suggestions of the right way to do it though.

Comment: Dour, when you say to put each Id in a separate row, do you mean its own column? like a isAction, isFighter, etc? I don't understand

Comment: post your existing tables using `show create table` and might make a suggestion. Please also mention your favourite programming language

Comment: I haven't created the Genres table yet. Right now, my 'games' table just has a column for 'genres' and it's like 'Puzzle, Action, Adventure'

Comment: But the user selects those with a checkbox system. Before I did much work to normalize this pattern, I was exploring options.

I am using nodeJS btw

Comment: why don't you completely edit this question, and post alll that. You speak of a Generes table but it isn't clear which of the two tables that is

Comment: @e4c5 Thank you for the book recommendation "SQL Antipatterns" - Bill Karwin; I've taken over a part of software with comma delimited ids in a database table - my first contact with a MySQL, didn't know that this was a common pitfall. I took the wrong approach.. Thanks Tom.

Comment: glad the comments were usefull @TomKuschel